# regex - split string

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I need to splite string with file name, in 5 parts, as an example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
pkg_re='(.+)-[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^.]+)\.chi.zst*'

[[ $str =~ $pkg_re ]] &&
   pkg_base = ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
   pkg_arch = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

echo $pkg_base
echo $pkg_arch
```

The blocks must be as follows:

```
block 1 - python-zope-proxy # pkg_base
block 2 - 4.3.5-1           # pkg_version_build
block 3 - 4.3.5             # pkg_version
block 4 - 1                 # pkg_build
block 5 - x86_64            # pkg_arch
```

With the regex below, I get block 1 and block 5, as shown above.

```
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
pkg_re='(.+)-[^-]+-[0-9]+-([^.]+)\.chi.zst*'

[[ $str =~ $pkg_re ]] &&
    pkg_base = ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    pkg_arch = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
```

The expression would also have to treat as file name strings in the following cases:

```
str="python-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
str="python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
```

Comment: I think you can add some extra capturing groups, escape the last dot and remove the asterix after the last t if you just want to match a single t `(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst` https://regex101.com/r/CSeGSk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird perfect!

Comment: @Thefourthbird in some situations the regex doesn't work, where should I post and explain what didn't work?

Comment: You could add a comment under the answer for which scenario it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add nested capturing groups to get the values. Note to escape the last dot and remove the asterix after `t*` as it will match 0+ times a `t`

```
(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CSeGSk/1) and a [bash demo](https://tio.run/##bY7NbsIwEITvfootjSBVZachP2oPOQCqxIVL6c0kEQlWHbWKIztEgYq@erCFKiBwm935ZneyteJd9/jgbJV0sqJ0WNlAppcIqVpGg2pXc1HivagYrqRod9gnHgmwi9vXMA19kvOC7FU9QNX3VypZNLLJ8xO2bZrg2Aj6gt@0MCohWqxMYmUiI4QoBUu/gegPrFMe4hiGQwQAZtZFWGT9TifLefrxvph8zubUjQ//dsOkKkSZZtviZ9Pnxjdcn/DOxN0L/tlfy5z37UDbCLGci1N5U/ZivCp3u78M9gjzrOuO)

Answer (score 3):

Leaning more towards the K.I.S.S. principle ... a solution based on parameter expansions:

```
str="python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"

block1="${str//-[0-9].*/}"

block2="${str//${block1}-/}"
block2="${block2%-*}"

block3="${block2%%-*}"

block4="${block2#*-}"

block5="${str//${block1}-${block2}-/}"
block5="${block5%%.*}"

echo "block1:${block1}:"
echo "block2:${block2}:"
echo "block3:${block3}:"
echo "block4:${block4}:"
echo "block5:${block5}:"
```

This generates:

```
block1:python-zope-proxy:
block2:4.3.5-1:
block3:4.3.5:
block4:1:
block5:x86_64:
```

Running against the three samples:

```
for str in "python-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst" "python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst" "python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst"
do
    echo "+++++++++++ ${str}"
    ... block1-block5 processing (copy from above) ...
done
```

And this generates:

```
+++++++++++ python-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst
block1:python:
block2:4.3.5-1:
block3:4.3.5:
block4:1:
block5:x86_64:
+++++++++++ python-zope-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst
block1:python-zope:
block2:4.3.5-1:
block3:4.3.5:
block4:1:
block5:x86_64:
+++++++++++ python-zope-proxy-4.3.5-1-x86_64.chi.zst
block1:python-zope-proxy:
block2:4.3.5-1:
block3:4.3.5:
block4:1:
block5:x86_64:
```